# C++: Exposing static global variable only through inline function

Tags: c++, encapsulation

I have a class that is necessarily singleton, called `Foo`. I've implemented its singletonness as static member functions. At the moment, my code looks like this:

Foo.h:

```
class Foo {
public:
    static void fillBarWithInfo(Bar &bar); // want to make this inline
};
```

Foo.cpp:

```
static Bar myBar;

static void qux() {
    myBar = ...;
}

void Foo::fillBarWithInfo(Bar &bar) {
    bar = myBar;
}
...
```

However, after some profiling, I've discovered that the overhead of calling `fillBarWithInfo` is fairly significant. And because the function is so short, I would prefer making it inline, and put the definition of the function in the header file.

However, I do not want to expose the variable `myBar` to the outside world (e.g. files including Foo.h). But how can accomplish both of these goals at once?

One solution is to make `myBar` a private static member of `Foo`. This works somewhat, but the problem is that `qux()`, which MUST be a static function, can't access it then.

Any other ideas? I suppose I could declare `extern Bar myBar;` in the header file but then users will have access to it, breaking my encapsulation. I want only to expose `myBar` through this inline function.

Comment: Not really an answer, but have you turned on link-time optimization?

Comment: You could violate encapsulation temporarily to just gather performance metrics. If making the function inline has significant savings, then you'll have a reason for delving into the code deeper and figuring out how to restructure the code to not lose performance and not compromise on encapsulation.

Comment: You can make `qux` a `friend`.

Comment: "I want only to expose myBar through this inline function." - it sounds like you actually want to expose `myBar` in two places: `fillBarWithInfo`, and `qux`.  There's nothing special about `qux`, therefore the `myBar` either must be publicly accessible, or `qux` must be friended.